# MS Outlook 2010 Crashes on Deletion of Emails from Mailbox

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I've been experiencing a weird issue with Office 2010 v14.0.7173.5000 (32 bit).

Whenever I try to delete an email from my mailbox (which is stored on Exchange but cached locally to an OST file) Outlook crashes.

It generally happens on the second deletion of an email within a list - Outlook halts for a second and then crashes out, closing the application altogether.

No event logs are left by Outlook or Windows system itself.

Any help on the matter would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your ost. scan the ost with ost scan tool. located in office installation directory